# OSX: change date format in multiple file names

Tags: regex, macos, command-line, sed, batch-rename

I have a large number of files in this format (iPhone camera):

```
Photo 31-12-13 12 59 59.jpg
```

How can I batch rename these files using the OSX command line to this (ISO) format:

```
2013-12-31 12 59 59.jpg
```

I have tried using the command below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for i in Photo*
do
  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's_Photo ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) (.*)_\3-\2-\1 \4_/'`”
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for i in Photo*; do
    mv "$i" "$(sed -E 's/^Photo ([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*) (.*)$/20\3-\2-\1 \4/' <<< "$i")"
done
```

Comment: You have a typo near the end of that line: doubled `"$i")`

Comment: Just tried, but it's not working, nothing changes.This is the output:
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: I actually tested it before posting the answer.

Comment: OK, tried it, but still nothing changes. Am I overlooking something?  I use Terminal to cd to the right dir and then paste at the prompt.

Comment: It outputs a number of lines, here's one: mv Photo 19-12-13 17 29 10.jpg Photo 19-12-13 17 29 10.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You have a stray slash.

sed's basic regular expressions need lots of backslashes. Try one of

```
mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -r 's_Photo ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)_\3-\2-\1_')"
mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed 's_Photo \([0-9]\+\)-\([0-9]\+\)-\([0-9]\+\)_\3-\2-\1_')"
```

Note you don't have to capture the end of the line just to refer to it unchanged.

---

Also the ending double quote at the end of the line is not a plain double quote:

```
$ od -c <<< '  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed '\''s_Photo ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) (.*)_\3-\2-\1 \4_/'\''`”'
0000000           m   v       "   $   i   "       "   `   e   c   h   o
0000020       $   i       |       s   e   d       '   s   _   P   h   o
0000040   t   o       (   [   0   -   9   ]   +   )   -   (   [   0   -
0000060   9   ]   +   )   -   (   [   0   -   9   ]   +   )       (   .
0000100   *   )   _   \   3   -   \   2   -   \   1       \   4   _   /
0000120   '   ` 342 200 235  \n
0000126
```

Comment: Just tried both lines but I get an error: sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
mv: rename Photo 19-12-13 17 29 10 (1).jpg to : No such file or directory